# recv only gets first 4 bytes of package

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I'm writing a client application in C++ to receive binary data via UDP broadcast, however I'm unable to receive anything beyond the first 4 bytes, regardless of the buffer size. I've checked the packets in Wireshark, and I can see that my machine is receiving roughly 1200 bytes of data. When I compare this to what my client is receiving, I can see that I'm getting the packets, however the remaining data is lost. Here's my code:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 4096
int main()
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int sockfd, i, nbyt;

    int *buf = (int*) malloc(BUFFERSIZE);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, "9011", &hints, &servinfo);

    sockfd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    bind(sockfd, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

    for (i=0;i<=45;i++)
    {
        nbyt = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFFERSIZE, 0);            
        fprintf(file, "%s %d; %s %x\n", "Bytes received:", nbyt, "Message:", *buf);
    }

    fclose(file);
    close(sockfd);
    free(buf);

    printf("%s\n", "Execution ended.");

    return 0;
}
```

An example of some of the data I'm receiving:

```
Bytes received: 1131; Message: 5b0
Bytes received: 1131; Message: 5b3
Bytes received: 1131; Message: 5b6
Bytes received: 1092; Message: 4e0
```

I've tried setting the socket to non-blocking with the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag, as this fixed the problem for a similar Python application, however this only returns errors:

```
Bytes received: -1; Message: 0
```

I'm relatively new to C++ and sockets, so it's possible there's something I'm just not seeing. Hopefully somebody can help me figure out what's wrong? I can provide additional information if necessary.

Comment: The data is there in the buffer. %x causes printf to look for an unsigned hexadecimal integer at the location pointed to by buf. So your program is doing what you _told_ it to do. You probably _wanted_ something else. Note that in your recv() call you have set a limit of BUFFERSIZE _bytes_, whereas the buffer you allocated was at least four times larger, depending on your platform's size for int. Allocate a buffer of chars, call recv() for data as you're doing now, and pass the buffer pointer to your handler routine for binary data. printf() is not a good choice for seeing binary contents.

Comment: @arayq2 OP allocates the buffer with `int *buf = (int*) malloc(BUFFERSIZE);` and last I checked, `malloc` takes a number of bytes. Are you thinking of `calloc`, maybe? Or C++ array-`new`?

Comment: @derobert You're right! :-)

Comment: Or you could just do the first option at the data init before passing and send the number of elements to the function due to the pointer decay - nice and dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're receiving it just fine. Your debug code just doesn't do what you think it does.

The `x` specifier to `printf` prints the unsigned int argument in hex. Integers on your platform are probably 32-bits. So you're only printing the first 4 bytes.

If you want to print the entire buffer in hex, you need to write the loop to do that yourself (or use a library, of course).

For example, and I warn you my C is a little rusty (and this is by far not the best performing way to do this) ... Also, this assumes your buffer is always a multiple of sizeof(int), or it'll lose some data:

```
nbyt = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFFERSIZE, 0);            
fprintf(file, "%s %d; %s\n", "Bytes received:", nbyt, "Message:");
for (offset = 0; offset < nbyt/sizeof(int); ++offset) {
    fprintf(file, "%x ", buf[offset]);
}
fprintf(file, "\n");
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks for helping me out! I was looking for the problem in the wrong place the whole time. Now that I know I'm getting everything fine it's just a matter of me pounding out the details. Thanks again and thanks also to all those who answered!

Comment: @user1896512 Please feel free to accept the answer then, by clicking the checkbox next to it... Or not, its up to you.

Answer (score 1):

`*buf` in your code means *the first integer from the array of the received data*, so you are printing just four first bytes of the received UDP payload.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the already mentioned format error, if you receive a '\0' char, a formatted print with %s will cut the string there, regardless of the actual number of chars received.

For debugging plaintext, I used below code:

```
char escaped_char(char c)
{
    char escapable[12] =    {'\a','\b','\f','\n','\r','\t','\v','\\','\'','\"','\?','\0'};
    char escaped[12]   =    { 'a', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', 'v','\\','\'','\"', '?', '0'};

    const char* escapable_end = escapable + 12;
    const char* ec;

    for(ec = escapable;ec != escapable_end;++ec)
    {
        if(c == *ec) return escaped[ec-escapable];
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @param   buf     input buffer to escape
 * @param   len     length of contents in buf
 * @param   outlen  pointer to an integer, which receives the length of the returned string
 * @return          A newly allocated, C style escaped string, NULL on error
 * @warning         A returned string must be freed with free()
 */
char* aescape(const char* buf,size_t len,size_t* outlen)
{
    const char* buf_end = buf + len;
    const char* c;
    char ec;
    char* result;

    assert(buf && outlen);

    (*outlen) = len;

    for(c = buf;c != buf_end;++c)
    {
        if(escaped_char(*c))
        {
            ++*outlen;
        }
    }
    result = malloc((*outlen)+1);
    assert(result != NULL);
    if(result)
    {
        if((*outlen) > len)
        {
            char* out = result;
            for(c = buf;c != buf_end;++c)
            {
                ec = escaped_char(*c);
                if(ec)
                {
                    *out++ = '\\';
                    *out++ = ec;
                }
                else
                {
                    *out++ = *c;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(result,buf,len);
        }
        result[(*outlen)] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        (*outlen) = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```